# Trying to update my users password using AddPasswordAsync but passwords always left as null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, razor-pages

So i've got 2 tables one for Editing user roles and one fore editing user accounts the roles table allows me to delete and add roles perfectly fine but i'm having trouble with updating passwords. The passwords seem to be getting deleted but not updated with the new one specified.

```
<br>
<h3>Roles Table</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>Id</th><th>User Roles</th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var roles in Model.roles)
        {

            <tr>
                <td> @roles.Id</td>
                <td> @roles.Name</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger order-button float-right" asp-page="/ManageRoles" asp-route-id="Delete" asp-page-handler="Delete">Delete Roles </a></td>
            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>

</table>
<form method="post">
    <div class="flex">
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.roleName">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table table-striped" style="margin-top: 100px;">
    <thead>
        <tr> <th>Id</th><th>User Account</th> </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var users in Model.users)
        {

            <tr>
                <td> @users.Id</td>
                <td> @users.Email</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger order-button float-right" asp-page="/ManageRoles" asp-route-id="DeleteUser" asp-page-handler="DeleteUser">Delete User </a></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Update" asp-route-id="@users.Id">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.NewPassword">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update Password </button>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    }
    </tbody>

</table>
```

So heres my Page model class below

```
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        public List <IdentityRole> roles { get; set; }
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string roleName { get; set; }
        public List <AppUser> users { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string userId { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
      
        
        



        public AdminDashboardModel(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        
        public void OnGet()
        {
            roles = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        }

        public async Task <IActionResult> OnGetDeleteAsync()
        {
           var role =  await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
            await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(role);
            return RedirectToPage("/AdminDashboard");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (roleName != null) 
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName.Trim()));
            return RedirectToPage("/AdminDashboard");
            
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDeleteUserAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
            await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            return RedirectToPage("/AdminDashboard");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
            await _userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);
            await _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, NewPassword);
            return RedirectToPage("/AdminDashboard");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RyanWilson this seems to be Razer Pages, not mvc

Comment: Yes its razor not mvc

Comment: How about use method `ResetPassword`?

Answer (score -1):

Try it with this bit of code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdateAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(Id);
    var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user)
    var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, NewPassword);
    //validate result
    if(result.Succeeded) {
        return RedirectToPage("/AdminDashboard");
    }
    //handle errors
    throw new Exception()
}
```

You don't actually need to validate the result, but things tend to go sideways. Always better to have error handling.

The generated token validates the action of changing the password against the system. If a user would want to reset their password, because they forgot theirs, you would also need to generate such a token, send it to their email and then let the user choose a new password.

Alternatively you could just use `UserManager.UpdatePasswordHash`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.updatepasswordhash?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
var result = await _userManager.UpdatePasswordHash(user, NewPassword, true|false);
```